# Use Outlook PST placed on NAS on 2 Outlook Clients

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

Problem: I need a shared Calendar on both PCs.

Idea: Create a new Outlook datafile and place it on a network drive. Now I have two PCs, add the datafile on both in Outlook. When I add a new Event on PC1 I believe I should be able to see the Event on PC2 aswell, right? Anyone know if this works? Feel free to share different ideas how to solve the problem.

I found a couple threads online about my idea, some say it doesn't work, others say it works fine in newer versions. I'm running Outlook 2019 on both.

Why am I thinking about it? The only alternative for me would be to use Google, but it seems like working with all those FreeSoftware is worse then getting a NAS and doing the way I described above.

Comment: A PST can only be opened by one instance of Outlook at a time.  You'll need to do the sharing on the server side versus the client.

Comment: And do not place on a NAS. You can damage the PST this way. It is a one user (only)  file

Comment: This sounds bad for me. Is there any alternative then besides playing around with converting Softwares/Plugins for CalDAV to Outlook? I'm trying to help out my brother. He's a one man company and he got 2 PCs. There is no need to get Servers. He didn't liked the idea of using Office365.

Comment: It is not recommended to put your PST file on a network location since it can damage your PST file.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e5d5f553-fde1-44cf-8cbd-723ea392aab8/outlook-pst-file-store-in-network-location?forum=outlook. If you'd like to share calendar on both PCs, it is suggested to use an Exchange account such as Outlook.com, then configure your Outlook.com account on both PCs(Outlook client), then your calendar will be synced between two PCs.

Comment: Facepalm. Thinking about Google instead of Microsoft yeah. Could be a solution. Gonna have to look this up.